# Windows CA: switch self-signed root certificate with certificate from provider

Tags: windows, certificate-authority

In our Windows Domain (2008R2 and 2012R2 Servers), we are running a Domain CA. The root certificate is a self-signed certificate.

We also have a x.509 certificate from our internet provider (mostly for our websites), signed by a trusted internet CA.

What i want to do is remove the self-signed root certificate from the Windows CA and replace it with the certificate from our provider.

Two questions:
1. is this even possible? Can i use a certificate from a trusted CA as root certificate for my own CA?
2. will this be possible without rebuiliding the whole domain? I think the domain controlers need the certificates for their LDAP communication, what will happen if i just switch the root certificate they used to create their own certificates?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> We also have a x.509 certificate from our internet provider (mostly
>   for our websites), signed by a trusted internet CA.

Sorry this is usually not possible. There are `basic constraints` in X.509 certificate and one of them says if it can sign other certificates. Usually, CAs don't issue such certificates to non-CAs.

This is an example of a cert allowed to sign other certs:

[image: cert allowed to sign other certs]

This is an example of a *normal* cert - it's disallowed to sign other certs:

[image: cert not allowed to sign other certs]

I wouldn't worry about it. Virtually **all** public CAs have self-signed root certificates, so why shouldn't your private CA have a self-signed root too?

Comment: Which attribute would this be, and what value should it have?
I found a field called "Base Constraints", with values "Subject Type=CA" and "Path Length Constraint=1".

Comment: Yes, as you see in screenshots, this attribute will allow you to sign certficates properly.

Comment: Your Edit and my comment just overlapped... We want to use a trusted certficate because we want to use s/MIME mail signing. If this is the wrong way to do it, please tell me...

Comment: After i know now that our "external" root certificate can sign certificates - how can i add this external root certificat as root of my Windows Certificate chain? Or how can i "switch" the root certificate?